# logic native plugins

Tags: logic

i own the complete waves plugins bundle, including some other top-shelf plugins. as much as i love Waves and cannot imagine a workflow without them, i find myself quite a lot using the straight-forward, basic native Logic plugins... especially the compressor, limiter and EQ. am i insane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not insane, I think Logic comes with a large amount of excellent plugins and instruments that stand up well to software far above its price range. Since the price drop a few years ago I think that Logic Studio has to be the best DAW in terms of value for money.

Comment: +1 on bang for your buck from Logic. I personally don't find it the most inspirational environment for composing. I just feel like it does things in a very 1998 way. Then again, I'm a weirdo and prefer to do everything in Audiomulch so take that with a grain of salt. :)

Some of the instruments and effects in Logic are drop dead awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever works and sounds good is good!

I've often found myself using Logic's compressor over many of the Waves/other plugins. There's nothing wrong. It's all about the sound you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer Logic plugins for Sound Design cause I think they give a more "flat" processing. Waves I always thought give more musicality in their processing!

Also Pro Tools plugins are awesome if you are good with the details!

Answer (score 1):

I really like the ssl compressor and channels, but what was said before is the truth.  It depends on personal preference and the situation.  A ssl comp would probably not fit a metal mix as well as the logic one, but would be better for jazz rock.  Best to experiment and find what works the best.  Non destructive editing is why digital is great.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably one of the most common statements about Logic 9 is that the plugins are great.  Other than that people complain about the sound quality in my experience.  I always loved Space Designer but Logic and I got divorced awhile ago, when I found a new woman--Pro Tools.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a a provoking question, but did you buy all those plugins? (Just curious, because you were asking about pirate samples a while ago)
If I am wrong, I'm sorry about asking.

Comment: no provocation intended :) and yes, i've purchased the complete bundle.

Comment: ok =). So I guess you bought those plugins for a certain reason. EG the Q10 is better than the Logic EQ, since you can do independent L/R EQ adjustments (or M/S ). In my opinion most of those plugins advantages is not 100% about the actual sound of it, but about the handling of the plugin ( for example those ONE Knob plugins by waves.)